# Deleting duplicate in a file without creating new file bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, duplicates

I've been looking around here on how to delete duplicates in a file with preserving the order of the file. However, I couldn't find a command that deletes in place and not have to create a new file.

example

sample.txt

```
one
two
three
one
four
one
five
```

after deleting duplicates

sample.txt

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU `awk` has the `inplace` option.

```
gawk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' file.txt
```